# SQL Server auto increment on composite key

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a composite key in SQL Server 2008 (this was done for various reasons/DB design, but a main one is b/c we are moving to a new schema and need to preserve data).

So I've created a new table with a foreign key reference and have been working on migrating data. Data retrieval/edits are easy. Now, I'd like to be able to insert new records (using a given FK value) and be able to auto-increment newly inserted record IDs and have all of this handled within a stored proc.

Example

Table 1:  (`id, type make up the composite key`)

```
id   data  type(FK)
1     A      1
2     B      1
1     C      2
2     D      2
3     B      1
4     C      1
3     A      2
4     G      2
```

Now if I have another entry (data F of type 2), I'd like to be able to pass in record data (`data=F,type=2`) and have the stored proc insert (5,F,2)..in a threadsafe/concurrency/scalable manner (ie w/o doing `SELECT MAX(id)...`).  Any ideas/thoughts on the best way to do this from the SQL Server community?

Comment: nope, data is unrestricted.  a composite primary key is made of (id and type).

Comment: But if someone tried to add (another) G of type 2 would it be rejected or would it become 5, G, 2?

Answer (score 4):

The **easiest** and **safest** solution would be to just add an `INT IDENTITY` column to the table and let SQL Server deal with the intricacies of updating the identity value. That would give you a real, proper, and solid identity value - regardless of the value of your `type` column.

In SQL Server 2012, you could use the `SEQUENCE` database object to create a sequence for each value of `type` that you need - but the 2008 version doesn't have anything like that yet, unfortunately.

Comment: This will give me the results I'm looking for, just thought there might be another way to do this w/o adding a column to mitigate concurrency/sync/multithreading issues - one user in the middle of doing an insert while another is inserting as well.  Also didn't want to lock the table.

Comment: @RajTirbany: if you can get onto SQL Server 2012 - then the sequences might be an alternative. For SQL Server 2008 unfortunately, there's really nothing as good and simple as an `IDENTITY` column ...

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it, assuming that the data that you want to insert is on another table (Table2):

```
INSERT INTO Table1(id, data, type)
SELECT  ISNULL(B.MaxId,0) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.type ORDER BY A.data) AS Id,
        A.data,
        A.type
FROM Table2 A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT type, MAX(id) MaxId 
            FROM Table1 
            GROUP BY type) B
ON A.type = B.type
```

As @marc_s said on a comment: **Using a MAX(Id) approach is typically not safe under concurrency load**

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth do you want to *store* this data when you can always derive it at query time, and guarantee that it be accurate?

```
SELECT 
  [type], data, 
  id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [type] ORDER BY data)
FROM dbo.table
ORDER BY [type], id;
```

The way you want to do it, you're going to need a trigger (or multiple) to maintain the information in the table as the data changes. For example, what happens when you run the following queries:

```
DELETE dbo.table WHERE data = 'B';

UPDATE dbo.table SET data = 'Z' WHERE data = 'C';
```

Don't store redundant data. You think it's going to save you something, but all it's going to do is require extra storage and create unnecessary maintenance grief.

Comment: thanks for the response.  In going through your feedback I'm unclear as to the redundant data but agree that it should not be a part of this solution/trying for 3NF.  The 'type' is a FK reference to a reference table; ID is being preserved from the old schema that's being replaced.